# Change mobile network mode (gsm, wcdma, auto)

Tags: android, android-networking, telephony

I want to change the preferred network mode ie. gsm or wcdma or auto, programmatically, from  code, on Android.

Is this possible, and if so how ?

Comment: You could look at the source code of the Android settings and see how _it_ does it. I guess all you need is is the "Secure settings" permission, and then you can modify the value directly from your code. Not sure though..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer is **NO**

We can open directly the settings app of mobile network settings to switch between "2G" and "allow 3G" networks.A direct switch is sadly not possible.

We can develop something which will show current network and allow user short-cut from the app where they can switch network.

Comment: hmm, but there must be such mechanism. Dont know why Android havent gave priviledge of using such stuff.

Comment: I think just because of the reason : Security and User Privacy.

Comment: is it not possible even on a ROOTed phone or using Android NDK?

Comment: @WojtekO. I have no idea on tha.

Comment: It is possible on a rooted device.

Comment: Please provide any link if available... thanks for giving the hope :) @rebel_UA

Comment: I can't, but you should reverse engineering default settings app, install your app to /system/app/ and add WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS to uses-permission. I don't know to why, but if you'll fun =)

Comment: So then, how do you open the relevant settings?

Answer (score 9):

### It is possible, I did it.

For this to work, your app **must** be signed with the system key or have carrier privilege. Otherwise the app will throw 
`java.lang.SecurityException: No modify permission or carrier privilege.`

My app runs on Android 5.1 Lollipop(API 22) and is signed with the system key, so this is the only configuration I can confirm for sure that works. I can't confirm the carrier privilege approach.

### AndroidManifest.xml

Add this permission to your app manifest. If you are using Android Studio, it will probably mark this line as an error because only system apps can have this permission. If you can sign your app with the system keys, don't worry.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

### Get Preferred Network

The return is defined in RILConstants.java, e.g. `RILConstants.NETWORK_MODE_WCDMA_PREF`

```
public int getPreferredNetwork() {
    Method method = getHiddenMethod("getPreferredNetworkType", TelephonyManager.class, null);
    int preferredNetwork = -1000;
    try {
        preferredNetwork = (int) method.invoke(mTelephonyManager);
        Log.i(TAG, "Preferred Network is ::: " + preferredNetwork);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return preferredNetwork;
}
```

### Set Preferred Method.

The parameter must be based on `RILConstants.java`, e.g.: `RILConstants.NETWORK_MODE_LTE_ONLY`

```
public void setPreferredNetwork(int networkType) {
    try {
        Method setPreferredNetwork = getHiddenMethod("setPreferredNetworkType",
                TelephonyManager.class, new Class[] {int.class});
        Boolean success = (Boolean)setPreferredNetwork.invoke(mTelephonyManager,
                networkType);
        Log.i(TAG, "Could set Network Type ::: " + (success.booleanValue() ? "YES" : "NO"));
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is an utility method to access the hidden API methods.

```
/**
 * Get a hidden method instance from a class
 * @param methodName The name of the method to be taken from the class
 * @param fromClass The name of the class that has the method
 * @return A Method instance that can be invoked
 */
public Method getHiddenMethod(String methodName, Class fromClass, Class[] params) {
    Method method = null;
    try {
        Class clazz = Class.forName(fromClass.getName());
        method = clazz.getMethod(methodName, params);
        method.setAccessible(true);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return method;
}
```

Comment: Great solution! Note that I got it working without signing my app (just clicked Run in Android Studio), but moving it into /system/priv-app/<appname>/<appname>.apk and having the MODIFY_PHONE_STATE permission declared in the manifest

Comment: Sure! There are more than one way of doing it. I believe when you run through Android Studio, it installs with more privileges, so it works, been a while now so I don't remember the details.

Comment: This is a great answer! Thanks. @BamsBamx are you saying you're running in the AS Device Emulator or on an actual phone?

Comment: I did that in a real device, Sony Xperia Z3 Compact running 6.0.1 @user1147688

Comment: @BamsBamx And is it on a **stock**, but rooted ROM?

Comment: @user1147688 yes, stock rooted... Remember to set proper permission to the system apk. And reboot after moving it to system

Comment: @BamsBamx. could you explain it for me. how to moving it into "/system/priv-app/<appname>/<appname>.apk". I dont got it

Comment: @NguyễnHoàng By "/system/priv-app/<appname>/<appname>.apk" he means that you need to copy your resulting APK file to that path on your devices storage. Replace the <appname> in that string with the name of your app.

Comment: I get exception : `NoSuchMethodException` for both setPreferredNetworkType and getPreferredNetworkType

Answer (score 4):

This is not an answer, but expanding on Tulio-F's answer.

The [RILConstants.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/telephony/java/com/android/internal/telephony/RILConstants.java) contain the following:

```
// NETWORK_MODE_* See ril.h RIL_REQUEST_SET_PREFERRED_NETWORK_TYPE 
int NETWORK_MODE_WCDMA_PREF              = 0;   // GSM/WCDMA (WCDMA preferred) 
int NETWORK_MODE_GSM_ONLY                = 1;   // GSM only 
int NETWORK_MODE_WCDMA_ONLY              = 2;   // WCDMA only 
int NETWORK_MODE_GSM_UMTS                = 3;   // GSM/WCDMA (auto mode, according to PRL)**    
int NETWORK_MODE_CDMA                    = 4;   // CDMA and EvDo (auto mode, according to PRL)**
int NETWORK_MODE_CDMA_NO_EVDO            = 5;   // CDMA only 
int NETWORK_MODE_EVDO_NO_CDMA            = 6;   // EvDo only 
int NETWORK_MODE_GLOBAL                  = 7;   // GSM/WCDMA, CDMA, and EvDo (auto mode, according to PRL)**
int NETWORK_MODE_LTE_CDMA_EVDO           = 8;   // LTE, CDMA and EvDo 
int NETWORK_MODE_LTE_GSM_WCDMA           = 9;   // LTE, GSM/WCDMA 
int NETWORK_MODE_LTE_CDMA_EVDO_GSM_WCDMA = 10;  // LTE, CDMA, EvDo, GSM/WCDMA 
int NETWORK_MODE_LTE_ONLY                = 11;  // LTE Only mode. 
int NETWORK_MODE_LTE_WCDMA               = 12;  // LTE/WCDMA 
int NETWORK_MODE_TDSCDMA_ONLY            = 13;  // TD-SCDMA only 
int NETWORK_MODE_TDSCDMA_WCDMA           = 14;  // TD-SCDMA and WCDMA 
int NETWORK_MODE_LTE_TDSCDMA             = 15;  // TD-SCDMA and LTE 
int NETWORK_MODE_TDSCDMA_GSM             = 16;  // TD-SCDMA and GSM 
int NETWORK_MODE_LTE_TDSCDMA_GSM         = 17;  // TD-SCDMA,GSM and LTE 
int NETWORK_MODE_TDSCDMA_GSM_WCDMA       = 18;  // TD-SCDMA, GSM/WCDMA 
int NETWORK_MODE_LTE_TDSCDMA_WCDMA       = 19;  // TD-SCDMA, WCDMA and LTE 
int NETWORK_MODE_LTE_TDSCDMA_GSM_WCDMA   = 20;  // TD-SCDMA, GSM/WCDMA and LTE 
int NETWORK_MODE_TDSCDMA_CDMA_EVDO_GSM_WCDMA     = 21;  // TD-SCDMA,EvDo,CDMA,GSM/WCDMA
int NETWORK_MODE_LTE_TDSCDMA_CDMA_EVDO_GSM_WCDMA = 22;  // TD-SCDMA/LTE/GSM/WCDMA, CDMA, and EvDo

int PREFERRED_NETWORK_MODE   = SystemProperties.getInt("ro.telephony.default_network", NETWORK_MODE_WCDMA_PREF);
```

Where:

`** = "AVAILABLE Application Settings menu"`

Answer (score 2):

For those still looking at this and can not signe their app with the system key.

You might want to use the [startActivityForResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)) method to redirect the user to a peculiar [activity_code](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#ACTION_NETWORK_OPERATOR_SETTINGS).

Some of these codes are not guaranteed with a matching activity (Due to the different flavours of Android)

In kotlin you could use something like this :

```
startActivityForResult(Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_NETWORK_OPERATOR_SETTINGS), 0)
```

of course don't forget to import the required libraries.

Remember that the user will have to navigate a bit into the menu. So maybe put some generic and textual explanation about the inputs/actions the user should do to land on the good settings page.

note1: it is possible that on some devices there is no implementations for choosing the prefered network.

note2: I would definitely recommand Tulio F. solution if you can obtain according privilegies.

Answer (score 1):

I had a device with Android API 23 and used the method from [Tulio F.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38926356/17472982), however with devices in API 25 it had a NoSuchMethodException. But I was able to change the setting with this code.

"Settings.Global.putInt(context.getContentResolver(), "preferred_network_mode1", [network type based on [RILConstants.java](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/telephony/java/com/android/internal/telephony/RILConstants.java)]);"