# Can I change the network type programmatically?

Tags: android

I want to switch between network type (like GSM to WCDMA) programmatically from my code, is it possible. I search but didn't get any solution. Please guide me here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change mobile network mode (gsm, wcdma, auto)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10170179/change-mobile-network-mode-gsm-wcdma-auto)

Answer (score 3):

Because of user privacy and security, apps are not allowed to change the preferred network type.

check out this answer: [Change mobile network mode (gsm, wcdma, auto)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10170179/change-mobile-network-mode-gsm-wcdma-auto)