# Set preferred network type

Tags: android

I want Android source code to set preferred network type from my android application.

I can read preferred network by following code.

```
Settings.Global.getString(context.getContentResolver(),Settings.Global.NETWORK_PREFERENCE)
```

Comment: Hi, pls check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of user privacy and security, apps are not allowed to change the preferred network type

check out this answer: [Change mobile network mode (gsm, wcdma, auto)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10170179/change-mobile-network-mode-gsm-wcdma-auto)

When you'll scroll the above link, you'll find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38926356/8164116). But when you'll go to your AndroidStudio and start adding the permissions to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file, you'll come across this :
[image: Proof]

Which says that the permission is granted only to the system apps.